# Is OptionParser in conflict with Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, optionparser

I'm trying to write a documentation for my project in Sphinx and whenever Sphinx encounters OptionParser in my module it gives me:

> sphinx-build: error: no such option: -b

I thought that it's impossible, so I wrote a simple module to check this:

```py
from optparse import OptionParser

"""some comment here"""

parser = OptionParser(conflict_handler='resolve')
parser.add_option('', '--force', action='store_true', dest='force', default=False, help='gqdel will skip asking questions, and delete them all.');
parser.add_option('', '--verbose', action='store_true', dest='verbose', default=False, help='Report additional information from gqdel')

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

"""and here"""

print "foo"
```

And it gives me the same error. My rst looks like this:

```
some title
==========

.. automodule:: test
   :members:
```

Comment: A more extensive solution and explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570114/python-sphinx-the-module-executes-module-level-statement-and-it-might-call-sys/60446946#60446946

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is what I think happens:

When Sphinx runs, [autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) imports your module and the toplevel code in the module is executed. An OptionParser instance is created, and it processes the command line arguments and options passed to sphinx-build, [one of which is **-b**](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#sphinx-build). Your OptionParser does not allow this option.

I would put the OptionParser code in a function so that it is not executed when the module is imported.

Comment: +1; the `parser.parse_args()` has no business at all in the module level code, and not just because sphynx complains about it.

Answer (score 5):

This did the trick for me, add this at the bottom.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
```