# sphinx-build: error: unrecognized arguments: -b html build/doctrees source build/html

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for documenting my project. when i am running `make html` i am getting this error.

I have installed `Sphinx v1.1.2` . There might be some error in some of `.rst`, files but This error message is unhelpful since i do not know which file to check as i have more than 100 `.rst` files. So it is difficult to check files one by one.

Is there any way to solve this error or at-least to find out which file is erroneous?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) used in your project? That module has an "unrecognized arguments" error message.

Comment: yes ``argparse`` is used in my project.

Comment: Then this might be a problem similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912025/is-optionparser-in-conflict-with-sphinx

Answer (score 3):

Check the module that was being processed just before this error. That module is probably missing `if __name__ == '__main__'` check.

The issue here is that:

- sphinx-apidoc (or whatever you used to generate your rsts) probably put automodule/autoclass/... in your rst.
- sphinx uses `autodoc` extension to fetch doc strings from teh .py files when it encounters the autoXXX directive in rst file.
- autodoc import the .py module to extract the doc strings from it.
- on `import` if a module by default assumes it's an executable only (i.e. doesn't have the `__main__` check) the you'll get the error.

What makes this is a pain in the a$$ error is that most developers would use `sys.argv[0]` and `sys.argv[0:]` in the error message displayed on wrong args, causing a completely unappropriate error message being printed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [sphinx-apidoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) and your package uses [setuptools with setup.py](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) in the same folder, make sure you hide away `setup()` call into `if 'main' == __name__:` construct.