# Does Sphinx run my code on executing 'make html'?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I inherited a rather large codebase that I want to create HTML documentation for. Since it is written in Python I decided to use Sphinx because the users of the code are accustomed to the design and functionality of the Python documentation that's created with Sphinx.
I used the command `sphinx-apidoc` to automatically create the `.rst` files. I imported the module path into `sys.path` so that Sphinx can find the code.

So far so good. However, when I try to create the HTML using the command `make html`, there are many tracebacks popping up and some of the examples in the codebase seem to get executed. What can be the reason for that and how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Examples in the code base, like, code after a `__main__`? Or doctests (you know, tests in a docstring) ?

Comment: Good question. I hesitate to run it again. The exact command for sphinx-apidoc was: `sphinx-apidoc -f -F -o . ../src` follows by `make html`. Would that initiate the execution of doctests? If so, how can I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: (1) check whether you have some code in the `__main__`; (2) if you're not using the [`doctest`](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/doctest.html) extension, you should befine. Check your configuration file to make sure.

Comment: The files automatically created by `sphinx-apidoc` will use the [sphinx.ext.autodoc](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html) extension. This extension evaluates definitions to obtain their `__doc__` attribute. So that can also be a cause of warnings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autodoc.html), Sphinx imports the documented modules, so all module-level code is executed. This happens every time you do "make html". In that sense, Sphinx does "run" your code.

You may have to organize your code a bit differently to make the errors go away (move module-level code to functions). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6912025/407651) for an example of what can happen.

This is my guess but it may not be the whole story. It's hard to say more without additional information.

Comment: and there is no easy to find way to run additional code to make those import go well; that's a shame

Answer (score 3):

```
def main():

    print('hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

This way your code will not be run.

Comment: A little more explanation would likely help the OP and others