# How should I solve the conflict of OptionParser and sphinx-build in a large project?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, optionparser

I have a large Python project with many external libraries I don't want to touch and I want to generate the documentation with sphinx. My problem is, whenever I execute "make html", I get this error:

```
...
usage: sphinx-build [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: sphinx-build --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: sphinx-build --help-commands
   or: sphinx-build cmd --help

error: option -b not recognized
make: *** [html] Fehler 1
```

I already figured out that this problem occurs when there is an OptionParser in some of the directories that I want to document ([Is OptionParser in conflict with sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912025/is-optionparser-in-conflict-with-sphinx)). I actually have many scripts that use the OptionParser in those directories and do not wrap it with `if __name__ == "__main__": ...`. My question is:

How can I generate the documentation without touching any of these scripts?

Is there a way to exclude those files/paths? I already tried exclude_patterns in my conf.py but this did not work. I do not know why.
Is there a way to catch that error?

### Update

The issue turned out to be a `setup.py` file in the tree parsed by `autodoc`.

Comment: The issue is not about OptionParser. Imagine one the scripts has `shutil.rmtree("/")` at the module level. Check whether autodoc extension respects `exclude_patterns` or that you specified correct glob patterns. Make sure to start from a clean state (no build artifacts).

Comment: You are right. It had nothing to do with OptionParser. I had a setup.py in one of the directories and this caused the error. Wrapping it with `if __name__ == "__main__": ...` is a quick fix that solved the problem. However, that does not solve the actual problem. How can I let autodoc respect the `exclude_patterns`?

Comment: `exclude_patterns` is for excluding .rst files, not for excluding Python source files.

Comment: If you cannot touch the modules/scripts that give you problems, the only solution I can think of is to write the documentation for these modules by hand (i.e., do not use autodoc for these modules).