# Is sphinxcontrib-autoprogram parsing arguments after grabbing the parser?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, argparse

I am creating a Python package with a command-line interface that uses the subcommand pattern: `kevlar count`, `kevlar partition`, and so on. The CLI works wonderfully as it is, and now I'm trying to add the CLI to my Sphinx documentation. In searching for a solution, I came across [sphinxcontrib-autoprogram](https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-autoprogram/) which seems to do exactly what I want, even explicitly handling subcommands. But when I execute the sphinx build, I get the following error.

```
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.6.3
loading pickled environment... not yet created
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 5 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 5 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 20%] cli
usage: sphinx-build [-h] [-v] [-l F] cmd ...
sphinx-build: error: argument cmd: invalid choice: 'html' (choose from 'reaugment', 'dump', 'novel', 'collect', 'mutate', 'assemble', 'filter', 'partition', 'count', 'localize')
make[1]: *** [html] Error 2
make: *** [doc] Error 2
```

It seems like the sphinx extension is not only creating the argparse object (expected), but is also calling `parse_args()` on it (unexpected). The "invalid" `html` argument comes from the sphinx command-line build invocation, but is being mistaken somewhere as one of the subcommands from my library's CLI.

My syntax seems to match the sphinxcontrib-autoprogram documentation.

```
.. autoprogram:: cli:parser
   :prog: kevlar
```

**What could be causing this behavior?**

---

I'm not sure if these details are relevant to the issue, but in case they are:

- the parser is defined in [`kevlar/cli/__init__.py:parser()`](https://github.com/dib-lab/kevlar/blob/7668a05b156e246c50996e6944e7031fb30bec1a/kevlar/cli/__init__.py)
- the subparsers for each command are defined in dedicated files in [kevlar/cli/](https://github.com/dib-lab/kevlar/tree/7668a05b156e246c50996e6944e7031fb30bec1a/kevlar/cli) (for example [kevlar/cli/count.py](https://github.com/dib-lab/kevlar/blob/7668a05b156e246c50996e6944e7031fb30bec1a/kevlar/cli/count.py))

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but this problem reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6912025/407651 (which is about optparse rather than argparse).

Answer (score 2):

You should load the `argparse` instance in a separate module that create the same `argparse` instance but doesn't execute the parser itself. Or your module could detect that it was loaded within autoprogram and exit after the `argparse` instance was constructed.

For example the PoC-Library uses a very huge `argparse` command line parser with lots of sub-parsers. The front-end script is this: [py/PoC.py](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/py/PoC.py?ts=2)

The docs directory contains a dummy front-end, that triggers an instantiation of `argparse`, but aborts after its construction.

**Code to dummy load PoC:**

```
from sys import path as sys_path
sys_path.append("../py")

from PoC import PileOfCores

# entry point
parser = PileOfCores(False, False, False, True, sphinx=True).MainParser
```

Source: [docs/PoCSphinx.py](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/docs/PoCSphinx.py?ts=2)

**Code to load and abort if loaded by Sphinx:**

```
def __init__(self, debug, verbose, quiet, dryRun, sphinx=False):
    # Call the initializer of ILogable
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if quiet:      severity = Severity.Quiet
    elif debug:    severity = Severity.Debug
    elif verbose:  severity = Severity.Verbose
    else:          severity = Severity.Normal

    logger = Logger(severity, printToStdOut=True)
    ILogable.__init__(self, logger=logger)

    # Call the constructor of the ArgParseMixin
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    description = dedent("""\
        This is the PoC-Library Service Tool.
        """)
    epilog = "Pile-of-Cores"

    class HelpFormatter(RawDescriptionHelpFormatter):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs['max_help_position'] = 25
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    ArgParseMixin.__init__(self, description=description, epilog=epilog, formatter_class=HelpFormatter, add_help=False)
    if sphinx: return
```

Source: [py/PoC.py](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/py/PoC.py?ts=2#L191-L215)

The class PileOfCores implements a property to return the main-parser object `MainParser`, which is stored in the variable `parser` expected by `autoprogram`.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure your program uses [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), which is a requirement for `autoprogram`:

> scans `argparse.ArgumentParser` object, and then expands it into a set of `.. program::` and `.. option::` directives.

Second, the syntax you used might not be correct.  It looks like you copy-pastad from the first example instead of reading its [usage](https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-autoprogram/#directive-autoprogram).  Specifically:

```
.. autoprogram:: module:parser
```

`module` is the dotted import name of the module, and `parser` is a variable that refers to an `argparse.ArgumentParser` object or a Python expression that creates and returns one.

Thus in your case, assuming that your `parser()` creates and returns an `argparse.ArgumentParser`, your syntax would be something like this or close to it:

```
.. autoprogram:: kevlar.cli:parser()
    :prog: kevlar
```

The hard part is figuring out the exact, correct `module:parser` substitution.

For comparing against another example, see the [source program](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/1.9-branch/pyramid/scripts/pcreate.py), source [reST file](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/1.9-branch/docs/pscripts/pcreate.rst), and [rendered HTML](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/pscripts/pcreate.html) of the Pyramid documentation of `pcreate`.

Comment: "The hard part is figuring out the exact, correct `module:parser` substitution." Umm, the error message makes it pretty clear that the correct function is being called. The problem is that the `ArgumentParser` object seems to be *executed* rather than *inspected*.